# Use lazy % formatting in logging functions pylint error message

Tags: python, logging, error-handling, formatting, pylint

I have a python function as follows, when enabled pylint to code scan, it throws me an lazy formatting error.

```
def modify_response(data):
    try:
        response = {}
        response["User_ID"] = data[0]["User_ID"]["S"]
        response["Triggered_Timestamp"] = data[0]["Triggered_Timestamp"]["S"]
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception("ModifyResponseError: {}".format(e))
        raise ModifyResponseError(json.dumps({"httpStatus": 501,"message": internal_error_message}))
```

Comment: Best practice is to use f-string. Change into `logging.exception(f"ModifyResponseError: {e}")`

Comment: @K.Mat you have the same problem with f-strings. See the answer of tdelaney.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Asssuming that the line is

```
logging.exception("ModifyResponseError: {}".format(e))
```

and the warning is

```
W1202: Use lazy % formatting in logging functions (logging-format-interpolation)
```

the logging functions should be passed a format string and parameters, instead of an already-formatted string. Otherwise you risk the formatting operation itself raising an exception before the logging happens. These are old school [printf style format strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting). pylint will complain about f-strings too for the same reasons.

the linter would be happy with

```
logging.exception("ModifyResponseError: %s", e)
```

See [`logging.debug`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.debug) for details.

Comment: In addition to saving from formatting exception, it also saves you from evaluating strings that might not be used at all. Example `log.debug(f"This is {bigfunc(foo, bar)}")` - assuming debug logs are not logged in prod, this will cause unnecessary string evaluation, just to be thrown away.

Comment: `log.debug("This is %s", bigfunc(foo, bar))` will also run bigfunc.

Comment: @BenediktS.Vogler - All of the loggers have this same problem. `bigfunc` runs before the logging function is called, incurring the cost. You would have to pull `bigfunc` out of the parameter list and call it conditionally like `if log.isEnabledFor("debug"): bf_result = bigfunc(foo, bar)`.